# How to connect few devices in one board game?

Tags: android

A few month ago I saw presentation of rice game where car goes through few screens (some how connected devices). The car was very smoothly "jump" from one screen to another. 
But now I cannot find anything about it. Can someone give me a hit how it was called? And how it was developed/programmed? Any framework name?[image]

Comment: You will need an OpenGL framework as on any game (LibGdx for example), the network part is up to you.

Comment: Unity might help u alot.